# Create configurable product via csv import from existing simple products

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6, import-products

In Magento there are already simple products that have a common attribute set, but there is NOT a configurable product that has these simple products in its configurations.

With the default product import via .csv, is there a way to create the configurable product and add the existing simple products to its configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Ends up my troubles were due to using and attribute code that wasn't all lower case. Always use all lowercase for your attribute codes. Example: use `my_code` instead of `My_Code`

For anyone else wondering, it ended up working when adding the simple product rows to the .csv first, followed by the configurable product. So it will update the simple products rows (if you send in new data) and then create the configurable.